# Data Explorer merge request - Query bug fixes

Tags: support, status-completed, data-explorer

I made a few changes to the Data Explorer to address [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107076/data-explorer-doesnt-save-a-changed-parameter-name-unless-something-more-substan), and ported some of the queries along the way to use Dapper. As part of those changes I reworked the code to pass the `QueryResults` object around a bit more instead of converting to and from a JSON string all of the time to save the request a bit of work, and hopefully didn't break anything in the process.

I also updated the schema used to validate the execution plan XML before transformation, because SQL Server started adding the undeclared `ForceScan` attribute to the output that's currently causing that feature to fail with " The 'ForceScan' attribute is not declared."

Changes can be found here: http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/list

Comment: Awesome, thanks! will looks at this first thing next week unless rchern beats me to it

Comment: Cool! I've got a number of things on my Data Explorer to-do list, so hopefully I can find some more time to start poking around too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done, merged it in ... keep the patches coming !!!

Comment: Nifty! Next one's almost ready, client-side updates this time :)